# Show that Var$(\beta_0)$ $\leq$ Var$(\beta'_0)$

Tags: least-squares

The least squares estimator of $\beta_0$ $=$ $(Y\bar)$ $-$ $\beta_1$$(X\bar)$ can be expressed as a linear function of $Y_i$. Let $(\beta'_0)$ be another unbiased estimator of $\beta_0$, say $(\beta'_0)$ $=$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n c_iY_i $$ where $c_i$ $=$ $a_i$ $+$ $b_i$. Show that Var$(\beta_0)$ $\leq$ Var$(\beta'_0)$

Intuitively it makes sense but how should i start proving this?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the variance of $\beta'$ and compare it to the variance of the OLS estimator. From the results you will be able to establish the inequality.

From the variance definition, you would have

$$Var(\beta ')= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_iY_i - \mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^n c_iY_i)\right)^2\right]$$
where $\mathbb{E}$ is the expectations operator and its empirical analogue is an average. You may replace $Y_i$ by the linear model describing it (e.g. $X_i+\epsilon_i$) and compare the results to the OLS estimator.

This link migth  help you: http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/xegbohtmlnode14.html

Comment: How would you calculate the variance of that?

Comment: I have edited my answer.